# how can i access a Java array element by using a variable?

Tags: java, arrays

I have prepared some Arrays that i will want to use later:

```
int[] A1a=new int[20];
int[] B1a=new int[30];
int[] A1b=new int[20];
int[] B1b=new int[30];
int[] A2a=new int[20];
int[] B2a=new int[30];
int[] C2a=new int[40];
int[] A2b=new int[20];
int[] B2b=new int[30];
int[] C2b=new int[40];
int[][] all={A1a, B1a, A1b, B1b, A2a, B2a, C2a, A2b, B2b, C2b};
```

After im asking in main method the user to type the room "A B C", the movie "1 2" and the time "a b". When he does that im connecting them together and im making the name of an Array.

How can i use that name to call the array??

That is what im doing but obviously it doesnt work :(...

```
public void showSeats(String room, int movie, String time) {
    String pinakas=room+movie+time;
    for (int i=0; i<("pinakas".length); i++){
        System.out.print("pinakas"[i]);
    }
```

*saying he typed 'A' '2' 'a' the "pinakas" will be "A2a" as a String

In conclusion after i make the arrays im practically asking the user what array would be used. But me asking him to type "char", "int", "char" and after that connecting those getting "A2a" in a string variable HOW can i use that string variable to call the array.

Comment: Arrays of integers appear to be the wrong daya type here.  If values like "A" and "1" and "a" are meaningful in the data, they need to be in the data.  Not just the names of variables.  Perhaps you want to have a `Room` class, a `Movie` class, etc.?  Whatever system you're modeling, model it as custom objects instead of trying to fit all of the information into an array of integers.

Comment: Supposingly these arrays are showing the seats that a cinema room has its movie and its time of cast.

Comment: So you might have a `Showtime` class which includes a start time, a running time, a reference to a `Movie` class, a reference to a `Room` class, and perhaps a collection of `Ticket` objects.  The `Room` class might have a collection of `Seat` objects.  Booking a ticket would involve selecting a `Showtime`, seeing the available `Seat` objects in its `Room`, and adding a `Ticket` object.  Each `Ticket` references a `Seat`.  There are probably other ways to model it, probably better ones (I've never built a cinema ticket tracker), but the point is that it's more complex than an array of integers.

Comment: You could use a Map, which could use a String as a key and an Integer as a value. Java does not have dynamic variable naming.

Comment: What is "pinakas"?

Comment: it is a String variable that its contect will be the same as one of the name of the arrays. In greek it means pinakas=array (translation)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would have to use reflection, which is too complicated and isn't worth it.
You could however use a Map<String, Integer[]> and then use the input from the user as the key of your map to find the proper array.

Edit: after reading some comments. I think you should better model your entities: Room, wich has a number or array of seats. Session, which has a Room (you could create the room from a factory), a time, and a movie (maybe an Enum)